# Finding the first row in a group using Pig

Tags: group-by, apache-pig

For a student database in the following format

```
Roll Number | School Name | Name | Age | Gender | Class | Subject | Marks
```

How to find out who got the highest for each class? The below query returns the entire group, but I am interested in finding the first row in the group.

```
grouped_records = group students by (school, class, roll);
agg_records = foreach grouped_records generate flatten(group),SUM(students.marks) as total;
ordered_records = order agg_records by school, class, total desc;
dump ordered_records;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-- Find out total marks of each student.
grouped_records = group students by (school, class, roll);
agg_records = foreach grouped_records generate flatten(group) as (school, class, roll), SUM(students.marks) as total;

-- Order students from each school, class pair by total and find highest marks roll

agg_records2 = group agg_records by (school, class);
ordered_records = foreach agg_records2 {
              ordered = order agg_records by total desc;
              first = limit ordered 1;
              generate flatten(group),first.roll;
          }

dump ordered_records;
```